# MS SQL How to count a number of consequent values in an ordered list

Tags: sql, sql-server

Imagine I have a table like this:

```
DatasourceID | Value | TimeStamp |
123          | 2.5   | 09:23:35  |
54           | 2.0   | 08:03:41  |
123          | 1.9   | 09:25:36  |
54           | 2.0   | 08:03:41  |
123          | 1.9   | 09:21:35  |
54           | 2.0   | 08:03:41  |
```

I need to find out whether each of datasource has two consequent values below 2.0 using timestamp as an ordering parameter.

By consequent values I mean consequent in time. So if we make a time ordered value list like 2.2, 1.9, 1.8 then the query shall detect the event. However, if the list like 1.9, 2.2, 1.8 then the query shall not detect the event.

would it be possible to do it without using the stored procedure?

Comment: Yes. It is possible. Please share the code of your stored procedure here ;)

Comment: Raj, thank you for your feedback and editing :-). I have no stored procedure and wanted to get some help on writing a query.

Comment: what you mean by *two consequent values*?

Comment: Oh. From your question, I assumed you are already doing it with a stored procedure. You do realize that SO is not a code writing service, don't you?

Comment: The idea of the question is to ask whether there is a query which can do the job. there is no intention to get the stored procedure code as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select DatasourceID, Timestamp
from (
    select DatasourceID,
      Timestamp,
      Value,
      lag(Value, 1, 5.0) over (partition by DatasourceID order by TimeStamp) as Previous
    from the_table
) s1
where Value < 2.0 and Previous < 2.0
```

The idea is to split by `DatasourceID`, order each partition by `TimeStamp` and compare the `Value` of each line with the previous line (in the same partition)

The [LAG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql) function is available since SQL Server 2012

Comment: Thanks a lot. Really appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by *two consequent values* but if you are looking for 2 values below 2.0 then you can do a `group by` with `having` like

```
select DatasourceID 
from tbl1
where Value < 2.0
group by DatasourceID 
having count(distinct value) = 2
```

Comment: Rahul, thank you for your comment. By consequent values I mean consequent in time. So if we make a time ordered list like 2.2, 1.9, 1.8 then the query shall detect the event. However if the list like 1.9, 2.2, 1.8 then the query shall not detect the event. Example you provided will not distinguish these two scenarious